# install pm2 or nodemon or forever on raspberry pi2 ArmV7 raspbian

Tags: raspbian

it seems that install fails mainly cause fsevents not supported, this my shell responses

```
npm install -g pm2 
...
npm WARN optional Skipping failed optional dependency /forever/chokidar/fsevents
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your operating system or architecture: fsevents@1.0.8
```

then pm2 (the same thing happens with nodemon or forever) does not work at all.

if i try to install fsevents only this is what i got:

```
sudo npm install -g  fsevents
npm ERR! Linux 4.1.13-v7+
npm ERR! argv "/opt/nodejs/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "fsevents"
npm ERR! node v5.7.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.6.0
npm ERR! code EBADPLATFORM
npm ERR! notsup Not compatible with your operating system or
architecture: fsevents@1.0.8
npm ERR! notsup Valid OS:    darwin
npm ERR! notsup Valid Arch:  any
npm ERR! notsup Actual OS:   linux
npm ERR! notsup Actual Arch: arm
```

maybe should i wait till fsevents compatibility?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Attempting to install fsevents on the Raspberry Pi doesn't even make sense. According to its [package page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fsevents), it's a library to get OS-X FSEvents. Since those don't exist on the RPi, it's not compatible.

The warning you get from pm2 specifically lists the dependency as optional. You'll loose some MacOS functionality, but you don't need that anyway.

Comment: This should be accepted as an answer.  It solved my worries about this issue (installing nodemon on Raspberry Pi 3).

Comment: @JeremyIglehart: I appreciate the upvote all the same :)